# How does a Beam runner determine the size of each bundle of a PCollection

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

According to [Apache Beam Execution Model - Bundling and persistence](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/):

**"Instead of processing all elements simultaneously, the elements in a PCollection are processed in bundles. The division of the collection into bundles is arbitrary and selected by the runner. This allows the runner to choose an appropriate middle-ground between persisting results after every element, and having to retry everything if there is a failure. For example, a streaming runner may prefer to process and commit small bundles, and a batch runner may prefer to process larger bundles."**

The paragraph suggests that the size of a bundle is arbitrary and determined by a runner. I have checked out the source code of Apache Beam, and looked into the Runner module in order to figure out how the runners determine the bundle size. However, I can't figure that out.

Can someone point out in which java class(es) or configuration file(s) the size of bundles is calculated? I am interested in how it works for the DirectRunner and Cloud Dataflow Runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally isn't a knob meant to be set, and infact its not an availabile knob in the open source code of the dataflow runner harness/beam sdk themselves. Runners make a choice when packing a bundle, based on the runner's preferences/goals for running a performant pipeline.

In Dataflow, some of the closed source backend systems are determining this based on a variety of factors, including the sharding, how much data is available for a particuler key, and the progress/throughput of the pipeline. The bundle size itself, is not based on any sort of static numbers, but picked dynamically based on what's currently happening inside the pipeline/workers.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into [BigQueryIo](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/630432e632e2cf10fc0ba4b66c8c5aa6efb5cea9/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/StreamingWriteTables.java#L211) you can see that they added a step that generate shard number per each record:

```
  .apply("ShardTableWrites", ParDo.of(new GenerateShardedTable<>(numShards)))
```

After that, they applied `Reshuffle`  and `GlobalWindow`  which is like group by shard id, now each bundle will be num of rows that generated with same shard id.

Putting larger shard number to achieve larger bundles.

I used it for BigTable read and write and it works perfect.

full code:

```
  PCollectionTuple tuple =
    tagged
        .apply(Reshuffle.of())
        // Put in the global window to ensure that DynamicDestinations side inputs are accessed
        // correctly.
        .apply(
            "GlobalWindow",
            Window.<KV<ShardedKey<String>, TableRowInfo<ElementT>>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                .triggering(DefaultTrigger.of())
                .discardingFiredPanes())
        .apply(
            "StreamingWrite",
            ParDo.of(
                    new StreamingWriteFn<>(
                        bigQueryServices,
                        retryPolicy,
                        failedInsertsTag,
                        errorContainer,
                        skipInvalidRows,
                        ignoreUnknownValues,
                        ignoreInsertIds,
                        toTableRow))
                .withOutputTags(mainOutputTag, TupleTagList.of(failedInsertsTag)));
```